# Remove commits before clone (forgot --depth 1)

Tags: git, github

I forgot to add `--depth 1` to my clone before starting a project. Is there a way to remove all commits from before your clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone your *local* repository using the `file://` protocol, and if you have made five commits since cloning, use the `--depth` option with `6`.

```
git clone file://C:/Users/<user>/Documents/my-repo --depth 6 my-repo2
```

Now you're in the same situation as you would have been if you initially cloned with `--depth 1`.

Comment: This is great, thank you. If I push that back to my remote, though, it won't remove the other commits will it? If it will - that's what I'm looking for. If not, do I need to create a new repo from the cloned local?

Comment: @itamar That's a new question. We've already answered how to handle forgetting `--depth 1`. Please mark this answer as correct. Then ask a new question on SO. You can then link to the new question in the comments.